# Create a ASP.Net web service and deploy on a remote server

Tags: asp.net, web-services, web

I need to create a web service in either 3.4 or 4.5 version of .net framework and deploy it into a windows server 2012 R2 OS.
IIS is been configured on the 2012 SEREVR R2 OS already.
Can anyone provide step-by-step information for this?
This web service would be consumed by a  java client for my project.

Also, would like to know what should be the approach, whether i need to wcf service & deploy the same in target server's IIS.

If I create:

asp.net web application in 4.5 framework and add a  web service -asmx -file will that be sufficient for me to deploy onto the target server?

How to take the web service code from my dev machine to another machine also.

Comment: Why don't use web api?

Comment: Please elaborate, am somewhat new to this .net web api terminology.Any links / source code / tutorials is appreciated!

Comment: Do you know asp.net mvc? Here is a good recource : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t090py6b0lM